# Is it possible to find out when a comment was liked on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to find out the date/time someone liked a comment or post on Facebook?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only way is to check your notifications, at [facebook.com/notifications](https://www.facebook.com/notifications).

Or the activity log of a page you administrate, at www.facebook.com/[*page id*]/allactivity

You cannot track time of likes people made on other people's posts.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not 100% convinced the times on there are accurate; in many cases it bunches together "A and B like your post C. 22.15". It's highly unlikely they both liked it at exactly 22.15. I suspect that time is time of the post, or the time one of them liked it.

Comment: That's right. I looked, and it's not the time of the post, so I guess it's a close to when they both liked it. 
On the top of the /notifications page you can choose to get notifications via an RSS feed. Maybe that way you can save the likes somewhere as soon as you get them.